# How to delete a commit and all of its children?

Tags: git, delete-file, git-commit

Let's say I have a commit, and I want to delete it, all its children, and any branches and tags that refer to it.

What do I do?

Really, only the references need deleted, after which

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

can be run.

Comment: Just to see if i understand you correctly: you want to delete all the code behind a certain commit?

Comment: @codeWizard I am currently checked out on a branch that is not a child of the commit. I want to delete the commit (which will therefore delete of its code), along with anything that directly or indirectly references that commit (which will delete all references to its code).

Comment: Still not clear to me: you have some commit that you want to delete with all the code that came after it in all other branches as well?

Comment: @codeWizard Internally, code is stored in the commits. Branches do not store code, but only point to commits. It is not necessarily chronological, but based on childhood. (If any other branches have the commit in its history, they get deleted as well).

Comment: you can use `git branch --contains <commit>` to see where this commit can be found, it that what you asked for?

Comment: @codeWizard Does that include tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100254/discussion-between-codewizard-and-pyrulez).

Comment: Updated the answer to display tags as well

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do it basically a rebase.
Keep in mind that if your changes need to be pushed to the server all your remote branches will require

#### Here is what you can do:

1. Find out which branches has the desired commit:

   ```
   # get the list of all the branches with the given commit
   git branch --contains <commit>

   # get the list of tags with this commit
   git tag --contains <commit>
   ```
2. Loop over those branches and reset them to the previous commit

   ```
   for ref in $(git branch --contains <sha1>); do ... ; done;
   ```